# "org.hibernate.HibernateException: Errors in named queries" in manyToMany join query

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

I have a manyToMany relationship between two tables when I write a join query between these two tables, I get an error while loading the project.

Here is the query:

```
@NamedQueries ({
@NamedQuery(name = "LicenseComponentDefinition.findByProductVerKeyType", query = "SELECT c from LicenseComponentDefinition c join c.licenseKeyTypes lkt WHERE lkt.keyTypeId = :keyTypeId AND WHERE c.product.productId = :productID AND c.productVersionByVersionStartId.versionId <= :versionId AND c.productVersionByVersionEndId.versionId >= :versionId")
```

})

And the entity class looks like below

```
private Set<LicenseKeyType> licenseKeyTypes = new HashSet<LicenseKeyType>(0);
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name = "component_definition_keytypes", catalog = "ldbredesigned", joinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "component_definition_id", nullable = false, updatable = false) }, inverseJoinColumns = {
                @JoinColumn(name = "license_key_type_id", nullable = false, updatable = false) })
public Set<LicenseKeyType> getLicenseKeyTypes() {
    return this.licenseKeyTypes;
}
```

It works fine when I remove the join clause from the query. Like below

```
SELECT c from LicenseComponentDefinition c WHERE c.product.productId = :productID AND c.productVersionByVersionStartId.versionId <= :versionId AND c.productVersionByVersionEndId.versionId >= :versionId
```

Can someone help?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your named query has 2 WHERE keywords in it:

```
SELECT c
from LicenseComponentDefinition c join c.licenseKeyTypes lkt 
WHERE lkt.keyTypeId = :keyTypeId 
AND WHERE c.product.productId = :productID
AND c.productVersionByVersionStartId.versionId <= :versionId 
AND c.productVersionByVersionEndId.versionId >= :versionId")
```

Shoot the 2nd one for starters.